# JxBrowser 4.3 download manger with download process and cancel function

Tags: java, swing, download, jxbrowser

I am using JxBrowser v4.3 and embedding it in Java Swing.

I need to add download manager which shows download process, cancel download or even download history. I have checked the APIs and found there is download manager class which can do this.

https://sites.google.com/a/teamdev.com/jxbrowser-support/jxbrowser-3/samples-3/download-handler

This link is not working. The error is `BrowserFactory.createBrowser is not defined`.

There are a couple of resources about download manager on internet, but none of them really helps me. I found something that says this needs Firefox engine to run the download manager. Basically, I wish I could do most of the things that a regular web browser can do when using JxBrowser, but downloading is the first step. Does anyone know how to start?